# Getting content inside tags inside string

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my string

```
var a ="<div id='render'>First<div class='render1'>Second</div></div>";
```

I need to take the text that is inside `render` and `render1`

How can i do this ?

I tried

```
var a ="<div id='render'>First<div class='render1'>Second</div></div>";
alert(a.getElementsByTagName("render")[0].innerHTML);
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgj2vugc/)

But i am getting error like

> Uncaught TypeError: a.getElementsByTagName is not a function

How can i do this

**Note :**

This is not content from site, i am trying to get text from other statement, so i am assigning the response to a variable and processing it.

I need to do this only using javascript

Comment: Are you doing this on a browser?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, i am doing it inside script tags

Comment: How is that not on a browser?

Comment: Sorry, i though you are asking whether i am doing it in console, i am trying that inside browser only

Comment: `a` is a String, not an HTML-DOM Object. A String has no function `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings don't have `getElementsByTagName`. But you can readily use the browser to parse the string and then use it on the result:

```js
var a = "<div id='render'>First<div class='render1'>Second</div></div>";
// Create an element to use to parse it
var div = document.createElement('div');
// Parse it
div.innerHTML = a;
// Find all divs in the result and show their innerHTML
Array.from(div.querySelectorAll("div")).forEach(function(div) {
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
});
```

Naturally you can do more advanced processing within the `forEach` callback if you want to extract other information.

Comment: @SA__: Yes. I suggest you read through the DOM API: [Spec](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR#dom4), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: The first iteration gives `First<div class="render1">Second</div>` is it possible to have first and second alone ?

Comment: @SA__: Again: Yes. I suggest you read through the DOM API: [Spec](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR#dom4), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught TypeError: a.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Yeah, it's not a function in this case, because you're trying to invoke function on string not element. Look at mdn for more clarifications:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

What's more: 'render' is not a tag anyway. You should use getElementById function to get outer div.